# Can Rails have dynamic relationships in has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a Lesson model which has many Completions like this:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :completions, as: :completable
  belongs_to :course
end
```

And each Completion belongs to a User as well:

```
class Completion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :completable, polymorphic: true
end
```

From my application perspective I'm only interested in the amount of completions for a certain lesson, so I've included a counter cache. In regard to the individual Completions, I'm only interested if the Lesson is completed by the current user (I'm using Devise).

Is there some way to create a dynamic has_one relationship of some kind, that uses the information from the current_user to query the Completion table?

for instance:

```
has_one :completion do
  def from_user current_user
    Completion.where(completable: self, user: current_user)
  end
end
```

Although this could work, I'm also having a polymorphic relationship. Rails is complaining that there's no foreign key called lesson_id. When I add a `foreign_key:` symbol, the do-end block stops working.

Any ideas?

Comment: why dont you make scope in Completion like `scope user_complition, ->(lesson, user){where(completeable: lesson, user: user )}`

Comment: And what would I do with that scope? Can I use it as part of the has_one?

Comment: no but it can fulfill your requirement where u need user lesson completion just call  `Complition.user_lesson_completion(lesson,user).first`

Comment: But that still will trigger multiple queries when viewing a Course (with many Lessons). I'm looking for a way to prevent this.

Comment: can u show complete associations so one can understand what you really want to achieve.  because according to current question statement i gave you possible solution

Comment: Sorry, I noticed my question is a bit vague on that subject... I'll consider upadting

Answer (score 0):

Why not passing both block and options to `has_many`?

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :completions, as: :completable do
    def from_user user
      if loaded?
        find {|c| c.user_id = user.id}
      else
        find(user_id: user.id)
      end
    end
  end
  belongs_to :course
end

@lesson = Lesson.last
# Association not loaded - executing sql query
@lesson.completions.from_user(current_user)
@lesson.completions
# Association loaded - no sql query
@lesson.completions.from_user(current_user)
```

NOTE: You cannot treat it as an association, so it cannot be preloaded on its own.

Comment: Is that possible? I thought having extra parameter in the has_many was causing me trouble. Thanks, I'm going to try this! This is exactly what I was looking for!